# hadoop hive using row_number()

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a dataset with many duplicating IDs. I just want to do a row_number() and take the first. If i have table1 left join with table2 and only take table2.rownumber=1, it works. but if i do a standalone without table join, it doesn't. I have the following code:

SELECT 
ID,
NAME,
NRIC,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) as RNK
FROM TABLE1
WHERE RNK=1;

The error message show that RNK is not a valid table column or alias etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a subquery or CTE to refer to a column alias for filtering:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, NRIC, RNK
FROM (SELECT t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) as RNK
      FROM TABLE1
     ) t1
WHERE RNK = 1;
```

This is true of all column aliases, even though defined by window functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’ve come across this. But after applying this, I still see multiple duplicating ID returned from the query.

Comment: @user-DY . . . If you are using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID . . .)`, then you cannot have duplicates for `ID`.  They may look the same, but they would be subtly different.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
create table dupes (
id string,
democode string,
extract_timestamp string
);
```

And:

```
insert into dupes (id, democode,extract_timestamp) values 
('1','code','2020')
,('2','code2','2020')
,('2','code22','2021')
,('3','code3','2020')
,('3','code33','2021')
,('3','code333','2012')
;
```

When:

```
SELECT id,democode,extract_timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT id,democode,extract_timestamp, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY extract_timestamp DESC) AS row_num
  FROM dupes 
) t1
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

Then:

```
+-----+-----------+--------------------+--+
| id  | democode  | extract_timestamp  |
+-----+-----------+--------------------+--+
| 1   | code      | 2020               |
| 2   | code22    | 2021               |
| 3   | code33    | 2021               |
+-----+-----------+--------------------+--+
```

Note that often tables are partitioned and that we might want to deduplicate within each partition. In which case we would add the partition key(s) into the `OVER` statement. For example if the table was partition by `report_date DATE` then we might use:

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, report_date ORDER BY extract_timestamp DESC) AS row_num
```